# Rails link_to question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, link-to

I am building a Kid's Chore App.  In application.html.erb I show a side bar listing the children's names:

```
  <div id="side">
    <%= link_to "Home", home_path %><br />
    <% @children.each do |child| %>
        <%= link_to child.name, child_path(child.id) %><br />
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Upon clicking a child's name, I want all chores to be displayed.. The code above will "show" the child when clicked.

I am thinking something like:

```
        <%= link_to child.name, chore_path %><br />
```

.. this does not work because:

1. I then lose the child_id... which I need for them to record their chores
2. I am routed to http://localhost:3000/chores/1 (I just want the chores index)

How can I keep the child_id as a variable in this example but display the chore index?

Cheers, Chris

Associations below:

```
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :completion, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :chores, :through => :completion

class Chore < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :completions
  has_many :kids, :through => :completions

class Completion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :child
  belongs_to :chore
```

Comment: Do individual children have their own sets of chores you want displayed? Or do you want each child to be able to select which chores they completed from a master list?

Comment: It almost sounds like you want to render Chores#index in your Children#show view. Is this right?

Comment: Since this question largely revolves around the relationship between the `Child`, `Chore` and `Competion` models you should be posting that code.

Comment: @adam... posted above
@josh... master list and render may be exactly what is needed. hmmm

Comment: submitted comment as solution. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
link_to child.name, chores_path(:child_id => child.id)
```

Then you can grab the child id in the action with `params[:child_id]`

The link will be to `/chores?child_id=1` for example.

Comment: That seems like the one... BUT see the associations I have provided above.  there is not a child_id field in the chores model.

Comment: @chris it doesn't have to be. This would make `child_id` a query-string parameter that you can see from the `chores_controller`.

Comment: Bingo.. thanks.  I assume, I will just do params[:child_id] when they "submit" the completed chore??

Comment: If it's a form, consider adding a hidden field with name `child_id` and value being the child's id.  That would be simplest.

Answer (score 0):

I generally create sub-routes for this scenario.

**routes.rb**

```
resources :children do
  resources :chores
end
```

**chores_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @child = Child.includes(:chores).find_by_id(params[:child_id])
  @chores = @child ? @child.chores : Chores.all
end
```

Now you can write your link as:

```
link_to child.name, child_chores_path(child)
```

[More on nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

Comment: I don't have a child_id field in the Chore model so this wont work.  I just need the chore index (list) so then the child can click "completed" and that will log the chore in the Completion Model.ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ChoresController#index
Couldn't find Child without an ID
Rails.root: /Users/chris/rails_projects/kids_chores
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:12:in `current_child'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:18:in `set_current_child'
Request
Parameters:
{"child_id"=>"1"}

Comment: most simply... I just need the link_to to redirect to the chores index and save child_id

the child then will click the chores he/she completed and the chore_id AND child_id will be stored in the Completion Model.

Comment: @chris if you need the child_id to save a chore, then there is a semantic relationship between children and chores. You should be associating the models instead of wiring up the fields manually. It will save you a lot of time in the long run.

Comment: @chris can a chore be assigned to more than one child? This is difficult to infer without seeing your model code.

Comment: @adam.. thanks for sticking with me here:

'Child:
  has_many :completion
  has_many :chores, :through=>:completion

Completion: 
  belongs_to :child
  belongs_to :chore

Chore:
  has_many :completion
  has_many :child, :through=>:completion'

Comment: @chris is there a reason why there needs to be a many-to-many relation between Child and Chore? Isn't this basically a todo list?

Comment: @adam.. the parents enter chores for the kids to do (same list each day).. the kids do them and "submit" which logs the completed chores in the Completion Model.  Each child has many chores and each chore is done by many children.

Comment: @chris how do you want the UI to work? are you thinking a check-box list of chores that update through AJAX? This doesn't sound like a traditional many-to-many form would be appropriate here.

Comment: @adam,  You are awesome.  I think the AJAX will be the ultimate solution but like in the Agile Web Dev Rails book...  I still need a "line_items" model to store the child's completed chores in order to know how much to pay them... make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you simply want to render the master list of Chores in the Children#show view, perhaps you could try a render `'chores/index'` in your children/show.html.erb in the appropriate location. Just make sure you get a master `@chores` variable set up in your `ChildrenController#show` method. Not sure if this is a complete solution, but there is my contribution.